# SQL create unique id WHERE not IN two table

Tags: sql

My code :

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 9999) AS random_num FROM product_list
WHERE 'random_num' NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT code_id FROM product_list) 
AND 'random_num' NOT EXISTS (SELECT p_code_id FROM item_group)
LIMIT 1
```

when im runit with PHP code the result its nothing, please advise.

Comment: "not working" -  is NOT a question

Comment: sorry about that @MitchWheat, becouse my english language not good :)

Comment: `WHERE 'random_num' NOT EXISTS` is invalid SQL. Column names must not be enclosed in single quotes. `'random_num'`  is a string constant. `random_num` is a column name. Plus: putting a column name (or string constant) in fron of the the `exists` operator is invalid as well

Comment: and what I have to do ?

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there.)

Comment: Avoid adding answers to your question. See [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(maxid) + 1
FROM (
SELECT MAX(code_id) maxid FROM product_list
UNION
SELECT MAX(p_code_id) maxid FROM item_group
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table, and adjust the `NOT EXISTS`s:

```
select random_num
from
(
  SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 9999) AS random_num
  FROM product_list
) dt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_list where random_num = code_id) 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM item_group where random_num = p_code_id)
LIMIT 1
```